# using a python generator to process large text files

Tags: python, generator, large-files, chunks

I'm new to using generators and have read around a bit but need some help processing large text files in chunks. I know this topic has been covered but example code has very limited explanations making it difficult to modify the code if one doesn't understand what is going on.

My problem is fairly simple, I have a series of large text files containing human genome sequencing data in the following format:

```
chr22   1   0
chr22   2   0
chr22   3   1
chr22   4   1
chr22   5   1
chr22   6   2
```

The files range between 1Gb and ~20Gb in length which is too big to read into RAM. So I would like to read the lines in chunks/bins of say 10000 lines at a time so that I can perform calculations on the final column in these bin sizes.

Based on this link [here](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/01/27/python-201-an-intro-to-generators/) I have written the following:

```
def read_large_file(file_object):
    """A generator function to read a large file lazily."""

    bin_size=5000
    start=0
    end=start+bin_size

    # Read a block from the file: data
    while True:
        data = file_object.readlines(end) 
        if not data:
            break
        start=start+bin_size
        end=end+bin_size
        yield data


def process_file(path):

    try:
        # Open a connection to the file
        with open(path) as file_handler:
            # Create a generator object for the file: gen_file
            for block in read_large_file(file_handler):
                print(block)
                # process block

    except (IOError, OSError):
        print("Error opening / processing file")    
    return    

if __name__ == '__main__':
            path='C:/path_to/input.txt'
    process_file(path)
```

within 'process_block' I expected the returned 'block' object to be a list 10000 elements long but its not? The first list is 843 elements. The second is 2394 elements?

I want to get back 'N' number of lines in a block but am very confused by what is happening here?

This solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519633/lazy-method-for-reading-big-file-in-python) seems like it could help but again I don't understand how to modify it to read N-lines at a time?

This [here](http://www.blopig.com/blog/2016/08/processing-large-files-using-python/) also looks like a really great solution but again, there isn't enough background explanation for me to understand enough to modify the code.

Any help would be really appreciated?

Comment: Use pandas https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: From the [docs for readlines()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=readlines#file.readlines): *"If the optional sizehint argument is present, instead of reading up to EOF, whole lines totalling approximately sizehint bytes"* So `readlines(10000)` is never going to get you 10,000 lines.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Instead of playing with offsets in the file, try to build and yield lists of 10000 elements from a loop:

```
def read_large_file(file_handler, block_size=10000):
    block = []
    for line in file_handler:
        block.append(line)
        if len(block) == block_size:
            yield block
            block = []

    # don't forget to yield the last block
    if block:
        yield block

with open(path) as file_handler:
    for block in read_large_file(file_handler):
        print(block)
```

Comment: This works great! And thanks for the explanation. I've accepted it as the answer because its a full working solution. Though I decided to to go with a pandas solution as suggested by Dimitrii K as its very concise and simple to understand. Will post my code below .

Answer (score 2):

Not a proper answer but finding out the why of this behaviour takes approximately 27 seconds:

```
(blook)bruno@bigb:~/Work/blookup/src/project$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
pythonrc start
pythonrc done
>>> help(file.readlines)

Help on method_descriptor:

readlines(...)
    readlines([size]) -> list of strings, each a line from the file.

    Call readline() repeatedly and return a list of the lines so read.
    The optional size argument, if given, is an approximate bound on the
    total number of bytes in the lines returned.
```

I understand that not everyone here is a professional programmer - and *of course* that the documentation is not always enough to solve a problem (and I happily answer those kind of questions), but really the number of questions where the answer is written in plain letters at the start of the doc becomes a bit annoying.

Comment: with respect, I had figured that the output was likely to do with the function returning bytes rather than lines, but just knowing that doesn't really help to get the function to return an object based on  lines which was the main objective of this post.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone else with a similar problem here is a solution based on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-to-read-a-6-gb-csv-file-with-pandas)

```
import pandas as pd

def process_file(path,binSize):

    for chunk in pd.read_csv(path, sep='\t', chunksize=binSize):
        print(chunk)
        print(chunk.ix[:,2]) # get 3rd col
        # Do something with chunk....  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path='path_to/infile.txt'
    binSize=5000
    process_file(path,binSize)
```